# Create a table of contents from specific BBCode tags in a string

Tags: php, bbcode

i have this code as my bbcode

```
[box=title|id]
text
[/box]
```

not i want php code that  count [box] tage in my code and list it as a **table of content**

example

```
[box=overview of the code|overview]
texttexttext
[/box]

[box=download of the code|download]
texttexttext
[/box]
```

i want code make a map or a table of content like `<a href="#id">title</a>`

```
<a href="#overview">overview of the code</a>
<a href="#download">download of the code</a>
```

Comment: So what's your questions? We're not here to write the code you want for you, we're here to help when you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Write a parser. You could use regular expressions but that gets ugly.

I think that's about as specific I can be without having to write a single line of code :D

Comment: relly regular expressions is my problem in the php, please try to help me

Comment: I know, that's why you should write a parser ;) Parsers are typically faster too than regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a preg_replace on your string:

```
preg_replace( "/\[box=([^|]*)\|(\w*)\][\s\w]*\[\/box\]/", "<a href='#$2'>$1></a>", $yourString );
```

The parens in the regex will "capture" the string inside and you can reference them with $index (hence the $1 and $2 in the replacement section of the code).

Comment: If you pass that your entire BBCode string, it will return a string of all the <a> tags as you requested.